# Possible incompatibility between ReplaceAll and LaplaceTransform

Tags: replacement, integral-transforms

I have a large symbolic expression containing many terms of the form, `LaplaceTransform[u2[z], z, s]`, with various functions for the first argument.  I wish to replace these terms by `l[u2[z]]`, but

```
LaplaceTransform[u2[z], z, s] /. LaplaceTransform[u_, z, s] -> l[u]
```

returns unevaluated.  On the other hand,

```
Hypergeometric1F1[u2[z], z, s] /. Hypergeometric1F1[u_, z, s] -> l[u]
```

or

```
Plus[u2[z], z, s] /. Plus[u_, z, s] -> l[u]
```

return `l[u2[z]]`, as expected.  What subtlety am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that the replacement rule LHS evaluates:

```
LaplaceTransform[u_, z, s] -> l[u]

(* Out[1402]= u_/s -> l[u] *)
```

To address this one can just prevent this with `HoldPattern`

```
LaplaceTransform[u2[z], z, s] /. 
 HoldPattern[LaplaceTransform[u_, z, s]] -> l[u]

(* Out[1401]= l[u2[z]] *)
```